# How do I use VueJS routing selectively on a small section of a static website

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, static-site

I have a vue template that pulls content from ButterCMS. The content is a summary of speakers that produces a list with mini bios and speaker images using the following code. It all works but I do not know how to use view router to load the full content either as a new page or in an overlay. I'm new to JS development and Vue so I'm really in way over my head. The docs aren't helping me with this use case.

I understand Vue routing when developing with Vue using the CLI and build tools. In this instance I'm only including Vue on a page to add some functionality to an existing site hosted on Surge. Any help would be appreciated here

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.buttercms.com/buttercms-1.1.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
var butter = Butter('MY API KEY');

var router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: []
});

var speakers = new Vue({
  el: '#speakers',

  data() {
     return {
       page_title: 'Global Summit 2018 Speakers',
       // Create array to hold the pages from ButterCMS API
       pages: [],
       query_param: `?page.slug`
     }
   },
   methods: {
     // Get List of Customer Pages
     getPages() {
       butter.page.list('speakers')
         .then((res) => {
           // console.log(res.data.data) // Check the results in the console
           this.pages = res.data.data
         })
     }
   },
   created() {
     // Fire on page creation
     this.getPages()
   }


})
</script>
```

```html
<section id="speakers">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading heading-center">
                    <template><h2><strong> {{ page_title }} </strong></h2></template>
                </div>

                <template>

                    <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(page,index) in pages" :key="page.slug + '_' + index">
                      <div class="team-member">
                        <div class="team-image">
                          <img v-if="page.fields.speaker_image" :src="page.fields.speaker_image" alt="">
                          <img v-else src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="team-desc">
                          <h3>{{ page.fields.speaker_name }}</h3>
                          <span><b>{{ page.fields.speaker_position }}</b></span></br>
                          <small v-if="page.fields.short_bio">{{ page.fields.short_bio }}</small>
                          <small v-else>Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis aliquet egestas purus.</small>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </template>
```

Comment: You can use modal and open it @click, that would be the fastest solution to show detailed info about a specific page.

Comment: @Latovic thanks do I need to use view router for that i.e. `<router-view>` tag to display the result?

Comment: So everything works for now? You just want to add an extra view or modal to display detailed information about some speaker. So on click method on the same view, you can display modal, HTML code for modal can be inside.

And you define a new method openDetails and it that method you can display modal, and change data inside modal.

data () {
    speakerInfo: null
}

and inside openDetails method you will fill speakerInfo object which will be displayed on modal.

Comment: @Latovic building the modal now I'll let you know how it goes ;)